# Java Enum field named "float"

Tags: java, enums

I have a code generator which generates enums based on some user-defined names. For some reason, if a user defines an enum with field e.g. "float", "switch" or some other compiler specific keyword, Java complains.

For example, I would like to define an enum with two fields "float" and "switch":

```
public enum TestEnum {
    float(100), switch(200);
}
```

However, Java thinks that it is some float variable and it does not understand the switch variable at all.

In C (if I am not mistaken) this makes no problem

```
enum TestEnum {
    float  = 100,
    switch = 200,
};
```

Is it possible to use such "names" for the enums somehow?

Comment: Java naming conventions are now well established and widely accepted.  Naming constant fields, such as enums, in the way that you have (all lower case) is thoroughly nonstandard and highly inadvisable.  Note that your problem disappears if you name the fields according to the established conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` and `switch` are keywords in Java and cannot be used as `enum` values.  I recommend following conventions and making them uppercase (i.e. `FLOAT`, `SWITCH`).

```
public enum TestEnum {
    FLOAT(100),
    SWITCH(200);

    TestEnum(int value) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in java.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Also the code style implies using of UPPER (divided by _ if necessary) case names for enum constansts.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ the same: these keywords (and all others) cannot be used (declared) as identifiers. Although the names of types and (for C++) classes in the standard library, which *can* be re-used (although it's usually confusing and unwise to do so), are all-lower like `time_t fpos_t string vector<T>` and thus resemble keywords, whereas Java standard library class names have capitals like `File ArrayList` making them visibly different.

Pascal and Ada also reserve keywords in general, but do not have these two keywords in particular.